# Spring boot on cloud 'No services have been found.'

Tags: spring-boot

A Spring Boot application (soap web services) works locally but on cloud after i do cf push shows :

'No services have been found.'

My related question : 
[Spring boot - Spring Cloud Config Server EXCEPTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722513/spring-boot-spring-cloud-config-server-exception)

Comment: Did u bind your service, to your application.?

Comment: @PraneethRamesh, For now I am just trying to deploy my spring-boot application which is using an internal properties file and not a spring-cloud-config-server. But even when i push this application to cloud it says 'No services have been found.' whereas locally when i do 'mvn spring-boot:run', my services run perfectly. I believe it is not able to identify cxf bean

Comment: Do you mean to say you cant push the app from cf cli.? do you use a manifest for pushing?? If yes show me your manifest

Comment: @PraneethRamesh, I can successfully push the app through cf cli but when i hit the url associated with my app, it shows 'No services have been found'. my manifest file contains :  applications:
- name: my-service-${random-word}
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  memory: 768M
  instances: 1
  path: target/my-service.jar
  env:
    JAVA_VERSION: 1.7.0_+

Comment: Check app status using the command cf app [app-name]. If the message status running then app is started. If it is notstarted/failed then look for the logs of the application using command cf logs [app-name] --recent. Check whats wrong with the starting of the application.

Comment: @PraneethRamesh  application is started and running, but when i hit the url 'no services found'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143219/discussion-between-tiya-and-praneeth-ramesh).